# How to fill an array through user input?

Tags: c#

I have been trying to fill up my array using user input in the form of an input box. I can do this one by one, using:

```
JobsArray[0] = InputBox("Enter Job type here", "JOB TYPE", ":)");
```

but I was asked to use a for loop as my Array contains only 3 elements. I am not sure how to run this loop to get the input into my array using the input box. Essentially to get the user input. I am using:

```
strJobs = InputBox ("Enter Job type here" , "JOB TYPE" , "" );
```

and I don't know now how to take that string and store it into the array. The for loop looks like:

```
for (intArrayCount = 0; intArrayCount < RatesArray.Length; ++intArrayCount)
```

and then, the inputs received will be used in a combo box.

Comment: Review the [String.Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx) method to better understand how to take an input string and convert into an array based on a defined deliminator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string[] JobsArray = new string[3];

for (intArrayCount = 0; intArrayCount < RatesArray.Length; ++intArrayCount)
{
  JobsArray[intArrayCount] = InputBox("Enter Job type here", "JOB TYPE", ":)");
}
```

or

```
List<string> JobsArray = new List<string>();

for (intArrayCount = 0; intArrayCount < RatesArray.Length; ++intArrayCount)
{
  JobsArray.Add(InputBox("Enter Job type here", "JOB TYPE", ":)"));
}

string[] newArray = JobsArray.ToArray();
```